# "List index out of range" for list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code:

```
    import random

    fixed_set = random.sample(range(1, 11), 6)
    test = [[random.sample(range(1, 11), 6)] for x in range(5)]

    for x in range(5):
        for j in range(6):
            print (test[x][j])
```

In line 7 "print (test[x][j])" I get this error "IndexError: list index out of range" and I don't exactly understand why it is happening and how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`random.sample(range(1, 11), 6)` returns a list itself and no need to use `[]` around that.

Try this:

```
import random

test = [random.sample(range(1, 11), 6) for x in range(5)]

for x in range(5):
    for j in range(6):
        print (test[x][j])
```

Comment: simple & clear. I have edited to remove the useless "fixed_set" line

Comment: Thanks @jean-francois-fabre! I just tried to copy paste question code. I didn't find out why that line being used there too.

Answer (score 0):

`random.sample(range(1, 11), 6)` is already returning a list, yet you are wrapping it with another list in `[[random.sample(range(1, 11), 6)] for x in range(5)]`, so change that line to this `[random.sample(range(1, 11), 6) for x in range(5)]` and your code should be fine:

```
import random

fixed_set = random.sample(range(1, 11), 6)
test = [random.sample(range(1, 11), 6) for x in range(5)]

for x in range(5):
    for j in range(6):
        print (test[x][j])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug your script.

The "test" variable is a list of lists of a single item which in turn is just a list of 6 integers in range 1-10 (inclusive).

For example:

```
[[[3, 2, 8, 9, 7, 6]], [[7, 1, 3, 2, 9, 5]], [[10, 9, 2, 4, 5, 1]], [[5, 7, 9, 3, 4, 1]], [[10, 9, 2, 7, 6, 3]]]
```

Is this what you want?
Maybe you just want it to be a list of 6-elements lists; in which case, you have to remove the set of squares around [random.sample(range(1, 11), 6)]

By the way: fixed_set is never used, in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
fixed_set = random.sample(range(1, 11), 6)  
test = [random.sample(range(1, 11), 6) for x in range(5)]
print (fixed_set)
print (test)
for x in range(5):
    for j in range(6):
        print (test[x][j])
```

This one helpful for you.
You Have to make `test` lists of list carefully.

Another Method in which just change `print` method.

```
import random
fixed_set = random.sample(range(1, 11), 6)
test = [[random.sample(range(1, 11), 6)] for x in range(5)]
print (fixed_set)
print (test)
for x in range(5):
    for j in range(6):
        print (test[x][0][j])
```

There are some change in the `print` method according to your `test` list.

Comment: it has been answered exactly the same more than 10 minutes already.

Comment: After reading the question I find the solution and just submit it.I did not check for other answers.